# Multivariable Gradient Descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

If I have a function $S: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that describes energy falloff in space.

I have a source $S$ positioned at $(S_x, S_y)$

and the intensity at any given point in space (x, y) is

$$ S(x, y) = \frac{1}{(S_x - x)^2 + (S_y - y)^2} $$

Now, I've measured the intensity of the space so I know the value of all $S(x, y)$; however, I don't know the position of the source $(S_x, S_y)$. I'd like to make an initial guess of the source's position and use gradient descent to find the position.

Since I know the intensity at every point in space I can make an energy function

$$E(S_x, S_y) = \sum_x \sum_y {\left(S(x, y) - \frac{1}{(S_x - x)^2 + (S_y - y)^2}\right)^2}$$

I'd like to know how to continue with this problem. The problem I'm having is I know intuitively that I need a gradient direction vector to tell me which way to step but if I take the derivative of my energy function I'll get a scalar function back which will give me how much but not how much to move in each direction.

Comment: What I notice is that the lines of equal intensity will always be circular. So an alternative would be to pick some reference point, find two other points with equal intensity, and use them together to triangulate the center. (That's obviously specialized to this case, of course.)

Comment: @Semiclassical yes, my real problem is more complicated I just wanted to use this toy problem so I could get the framework to apply to something more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this was solved awhile ago, but the key is that one needs a *gradient*, rather than a (total) derivative.

I'll just rewrite your energy function as:
$$
E(p,q) = \sum_x\sum_y \left[ S(x,y) - \frac{1}{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2} \right]^2
$$
Then the gradient is a vector, given by:
$$
\nabla E(p,q) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_pE \\
\partial_qE
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In this case, I think we get:
\begin{align*}
\partial_p E 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial p} \sum_x\sum_y \left[ S(x,y) - \frac{1}{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2} \right]^2 \\
&=  \sum_x\sum_y 2\left[ S(x,y) - \frac{1}{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2} \right] \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left( S(x,y) - \frac{1}{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2} \right)\\
&= \sum_x\sum_y 2\left[ S(x,y) - \frac{1}{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2} \right] \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left( - [{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2}]^{-1} \right)\\
&= \sum_x\sum_y 2\left[ S(x,y) - \frac{1}{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2} \right] \left( [{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2}]^{-2}(2p-x) \right)\\
&= 2\sum_x\sum_y \left[ S(x,y) - \frac{1}{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2} \right] 
\left( \frac{2p-x}{[{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2}]^{2}} \right)
\end{align*}
So by symmetry:
$$
\partial_q E = 2\sum_x\sum_y \left[ S(x,y) - \frac{1}{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2} \right] 
\left( \frac{2q-y}{[{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2}]^{2}} \right)
$$
Now, suppose you start at some guess value $(p_0,q_0)$. Then we run gradient descent from $t=1$ until convergence:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p_t \\
q_t
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{t-1} \\
q_{t-1}
\end{bmatrix}
- \eta_t \nabla E(p_{t-1},q_{t-1})
$$
where $\eta_t$ is the step size at time $t$.